# Wpf animation with mvvm pattern

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

The small example of work on animation, does not work variation of property of model, at animation

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="440" Width="732" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    <Canvas Name="canvMain" Height="360" Width="710" Grid.Row="1">
        <Rectangle Name="Zombi" Width="20" Height="40" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="{Binding Path=X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"></Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

```
public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            if (!double.IsNaN(value))
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }
    }

double pixelMetr = 0.715;

    private int GetPixel(double metr)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(metr / pixelMetr);
    }

private void StartZombi()
    {
        double distance = 250;
        double maxTime = (new Random()).Next(5, 10);

        PathGeometry animationPath = new PathGeometry();

        LineGeometry lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();
        lineGeometry.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        lineGeometry.EndPoint = new Point(GetPixel(distance), 0);

        animationPath.AddGeometry(lineGeometry);

        DoubleAnimationUsingPath animationX = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
        animationX.PathGeometry = animationPath;
        animationX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime);
        animationX.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animationX, Zombi);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationX, new PropertyPath(Canvas.RightProperty));

        Storyboard pathAnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        pathAnimationStoryboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        pathAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(animationX);

        pathAnimationStoryboard.Begin(this);
    }
```

Hello why does not work property change, I need to get the current value of the property ' canvas.right ', when the animation runs.

This is xaml code.

Comment: What is `TestX` for? If that is for display purposes, then you will need to notify the property change on that also.

Comment: TextX - Do not pay attention, this is just another property

Comment: Please show the rest of your XAML... I have no idea what control you are trying to animate even.

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't run your code. Please show your `GetPixel` method and then I can test it properly.

Comment: Update, i inserted GetPixel method

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found you a solution... all you need to do is to create a `DependencyProperty` for `X` and animate that instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("X", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));

public double X
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(XProperty); }
    set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
}
```

Then your animation method:

```
private void StartZombi()
{
    double distance = 250;
    double maxTime = (new Random()).Next(5, 10);

    PathGeometry animationPath = new PathGeometry();

    LineGeometry lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();
    lineGeometry.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    lineGeometry.EndPoint = new Point(GetPixel(distance), 0);

    animationPath.AddGeometry(lineGeometry);

    DoubleAnimationUsingPath animationX = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
    animationX.PathGeometry = animationPath;
    animationX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime);
    animationX.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animationX, This); // <<< 'This' is the Window.Name
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationX, 
        new PropertyPath(MainWindow.XProperty));

    Storyboard pathAnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    pathAnimationStoryboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    pathAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(animationX);

    pathAnimationStoryboard.Begin(this);
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Name="canvMain" Height="360" Width="710" Grid.Row="1">
        <Rectangle Name="Zombi" Width="20" Height="40" Stroke="Black" 
            StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Bottom="60" Canvas.Right="{Binding Path=X,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding X}" />
</Grid>
```

The last thing that you need to do to make this work is to set the `Window.Name` property to `"This"`.

To answer your original question as to why your code was not working, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that it was because the `Canvas.X` property is not plugged into the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and so your original CLR `X` property setter was never being called. There is a similar situation when `Binding` to the `Count` property of a collection... it won't update the UI when you add items to the collection, as it is not notifying the changes.